# Plain text does not show up in IE - weird gibberish instead

Tags: ajax, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I have a page that reads a file on my server and outputs it with Ajax. In Firefox and Chrome, the document displays properly, in IE9, either nothing is displayed, or some weird gibberish is shown.

The website is here: `http://199.193.248.80/test/test.html` Wait a few seconds in IE before the gibberish appears.

Screenshot:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/uligc.png]

Why does IE do this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Works for me as well in IE9.  Try using the developer tools and take a look at the Network and Script tabs and see what IE thinks it is receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me (IE9)...

But you might want to check if the page encoding is the same as the encoding of the returned html from the AJAX call..

I say this because the returned content-type header is `text/html;Charset=Windows-1252`, but with firebug i see unicode chars in there.. that might be fooling IE ...

(*you should probably add a `<meta charset="...">` to the html page as well*)

Comment: I added the charset to the page but it didn't seem to fix it for me.

Comment: @KevinDuke, i see some `bad` chars before the text in the tags (*of the returned html*) `����Setting CYCLE`, `����Connecting to`, `����Login` etc.. can you remove those to see if that fixes it ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What should I do to remove these chars or fix this issue?

Comment: @KevinDuke, that depends on how you are outputting the text in the `livelog.php` page.. (*and where you get the text from*)

Comment: the php file contains this: `$output = shell_exec('exec tail -n100 ' . $filename);`

`$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $output);`

`foreach($lines as $l)
  echo $l.<br>;`

Comment: @KevinDuke OK, so those chars are already in the filename you read... try changing the livelog.php `content-type` to to `utf-8` (*and your page as well*) to see if that is the issue. Alternatively (*if it fits your case*) you can remove the non-ascii chars before printing.. so try `echo preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]]/', '',$l).<br>;` instead..

Comment: I changed both charsets to UTF-8 and no change. The preg_replace made it so there was no output. Would you mine checking again with UTF-8 and see if you still see the weird characters?

Comment: @KevinDuke still works fine in IE9 for me, and also showing the wrong chars in firebug.. try `'/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/u'` as the regex string

Comment: That did not work either but it might be a local problem. I loaded the page on another computer with IE9 and it displayed properly.